# How to make only involved row's button enable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, foreach

I have a table and the body is using foreach loop.

```
 <?php foreach ($list as $test) : ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <?= form_open_multipart('/test/update/' . $test['id'], ['class' => 'needs-validation', 'novalidate' => '']); ?>
                            <?= form_dropdown(
                                'something',
                                $option,
                                $test['smt'],
                                ['required' => '', 'id' => 'smt2', 'class' => 'd-block col-12 form-control']
                            ); ?>
                        </td>

                        <td align="right"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" id="submit" disabled>SAVE UPDATE</a></td>

                        <?= form_close(); ?>
                       </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

For the javascript I do :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   

    $('select').on('change', function() {
           $('button').attr('disabled', false);
       });
    });
```

When user change the value of the drop down, then the 'Save Update' button will be enabled. For now, all the button will be enabled if user change on any drop down no matter in which row.
I wish to enabled only Save button in which row the drop down was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DOM traversal to find the `button` related to the `select` which raised the `change` event. You can get a reference to the `button` using the event that's passed to the handler function. From there you can get the nearest common `tr` using `closest()` and then `find()`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('select').on('change', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Note the use of `prop()` to set the `disabled` flag instead of `attr()`. Use of `prop()` is preferred where possible, as it avoid unnecessary accesses of the DOM which increases performance.

Comment: There have to be about a thousand of these table row/button questions now; is there a reference question yet?

Comment: @ChrisG I've often looked and in my experience whenever I've closed questions like this as a dupe, the issue then becomes 'how do I write the code to traverse the DOM to get what I need'. As such I find closing this type of question as a dupe is counter-productive, raises more questions and frustrates the OP. This is why I tend to answer them with a clear example for the given use case.

Comment: @ChrisG if you do find a canonical dupe target for this question type, do let me know though as I'll happily use it in future :)